# Directory Management Service SharePoint 2010 (Incoming email configuration)

Tags: service-application, incoming-email

We need to configure incoming email.

- Please explain how incoming e-mail messages are routed when the Directory Management Service is enabled? and disabled?
- What are the prerequisites for configuring the Directory Management Service?
- Is the Directory Management Service enable by default?
- What is Microsoft recommendation for incoming e-mail configuration?

Answer (score 3):

The SharePoint Directory Management service connects SharePoint sites to your organization's user directory to provide enhanced e-mail features. The benefit of using this service is that it enables users to create and manage e-mail distribution groups from SharePoint sites. This service also creates contacts in your organization's user directory so people can find e-mail-enabled SharePoint lists in their address books. However, using SharePoint Directory Management service requires more management because it is communicating with Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS).

Check [**this post**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288433.aspx) to know the detailed purpose of SharePoint Directory Management service.

Check [**this post**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287879.aspx) for detailed info on how DMS is configured for Incoming emails.